# How to re-log in in SVN in Eclipse in Windows 8?

Tags: eclipse, svn

How would I re-log in in SVN in Eclipse in Windows 8?

The problem was that I didn't have full access to the SVN and the checkout was failing. I thought my college could log in for me temporarily so I could get the needed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows 8, hit

```
Window key + q
```

Type in

```
Computer
```

In the address bar type in

```
%AppData%
```

Then go to

```
Roaming -> Subversion -> auth -> svn.simple
```

Then delete the file there. This way, you should be able to re-log in.